# Why do we run in diagonals when proving that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers

Why do we index the elements like this

[image]

but not finishing the 1/x elements and then going through 2/x then 3/x...

Comment: If you tried to "finish" the $1/x$ elements, then you would have already used up your whole list, without a chance to list fractions like $2/3$, $2/5$, etc. You have to take a bit at a time from each column.

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question, so I am leaving it as a comment, but I think it is still useful to point out: the real "explanation" of why we aren't doing that is simply because 1) we don't have to(!), we can choose whatever way we like of going through the rationals, and 2) the way we chose here does the job we want it to do.

Comment: You can't "finish" the $\frac{1}{x}$- elements, since there are infinitely many of them

Comment: May be You want to use the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable, but You would have to use a diagonal argument (or rather this sweeping method) to prove this!

Comment: Think of the rational numbers as guests in Hilbert's Hotel. If you put $\frac 1 1$ in room $1$, $\frac 1 2$ in room $2$ and so on, putting $\frac 1 n$ in room $n$, then which room number do you put $\frac 2 1$ in ?

Comment: Because the $2/x$ elements cannot be counted within finite time by your method. If you were to count each element of the list every second, it is clear you never reach 2. Countable means if I were to select an element from the set, I could count to it in finite time.

Comment: Because there are an infinite number of $\frac 1n$ and we can't "finish" an infinite number of things and "then" do something else.

Comment: " Countable means if I were to select an element from the set, I could count to it in finite time. "  THAT IS UTTERLY WRONG.  Countable can be infinite.  But it means it can be ordered in numbered list.

Comment: @fleablood that's the same thing.  If a set is ordered in a numbered list ( I assume you mean numbered using the natural numbers ), and I were to select an element, that element would have some natural number $n$ associated to it, and I could count to it in finite time.

Comment: But you can't count every element.   Oh, he meant you could count to just that element.  But that's true of *any* set countable or not.  Pick any real number and you can can't to it in three seconds if you choose it to be the third element.  So say you can count to it in a finite time seems a weird and pointless definition.

Comment: @fleablood It might be weird, but it's not pointless.  In your example of the reals, you ordered the numbers AFTER you choose which one to count to.  A perfectly correct definition of countable is that you can ( well-)order the set, and then for any element, you can count to it in finite time starting from the least element in that order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whatever method you choose of indexing the rationals, it has to satisfy the following basic property: for every rational number $x/y,$ there must be some positive integer $n$ such that $x/y$ is indexed by $n$ (slightly formally: there must exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\mapsto x/y$).

Let's attempt what you are describing. You are saying that we should start with $1/1,$ then go to $1/2,$ then $1/3,$ and so on; "and then" move on to $2/1,$ $2/2,$ etc.

Here's my problem with that. The indexing procedure you are describing takes each positive integer $n$ and maps it to $1/n$: $1$ maps to $1/1,$ $2$ maps to $1/2,$ and so on. So, here's my question to you: under your procedure, which positive number $n$ indexes $2/1$?

Note, as I said in the first paragraph, that in order for your procedure to be a proper procedure, there must be some value of $n$ so that $2/1$ is indexed by $n.$ You claim that your procedure is a proper indexing procedure; now you have to tell me what the value of $n$ is.

I'm sure that if you meditate on this you will see what the problem is. There is no such value of $n,$ so what you are attempting to do simply will not work; your procedure does not get through all the rationals, it only ever goes through the first row of the table. This is what people mean in the comments when they say that you "run out" of integers.

Comment: This makes everything clear. Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Simply because you cannot "finish" the elements $\dfrac1x$, and you would never index $\dfrac2x$.